# How should a client handle Location field in an HTTP response when it includes a username & password?

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse

The specification does not mention what to do of the username:password in a URI returned by a Location such as:

```
Location: http://user:secret@w3.org/hidden/pages
```

**Are we supposed to ignore such?** It doesn't seem to make sense, but I was wondering what if it were to happen (i.e. server misconfiguration, strange idea from some administrator/programmer...)

```
14.30 Location

The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the
Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request.
For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the server's preferred
URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The field value
consists of a single absolute URI.

       Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI

An example is:

       Location: http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/People.html

      Note: The Content-Location header field (section 14.14) differs
      from Location in that the Content-Location identifies the original
      location of the entity enclosed in the request. It is therefore
      possible for a response to contain header fields for both Location
      and Content-Location. Also see section 13.10 for cache
      requirements of some methods.
```

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) may have an answer. From [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-3.3):

```
...For example
a server could be responsible for authenticating content that
actually sits on another server. It would achieve this by having the
first 401 response include a domain directive whose value includes a
URI on the second server, and an opaque directive whose value
contains the state information. The client will retry the request, at
which time the server might respond with a 301/302 redirection,
pointing to the URI on the second server. The client will follow the
redirection, and pass an Authorization header , including the
<opaque> data.
```

So I interpret that to mean that the `Location` header you get back from an HTTP redirect shouldn't actually contain the `user:secret@` parts at all, just the rest of the example URL you gave, and that you (the client) would be responsible for remembering the user/pass you sent in the `Authorization` header of the original request that was redirected, and to pass the same header again in the second request.

**Update**

Also, [RFC 2396 section 3.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.2.2) has some words about using user/password in the URL:

```
Some URL schemes use the format "user:password" in the userinfo
field. This practice is NOT RECOMMENDED, because the passing of
authentication information in clear text (such as URI) has proven to
be a security risk in almost every case where it has been used.
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that putting those user and password in the URI is not wise. This being said, quite practical when you use a command line tool within your own organization (in which case the login and password may not be that useful though...) But that is pretty much what I was thinking. I should use the original user:password given by the user and ignore it from the Location URI.